# Understanding undefined as argument

Tags: javascript

I see javascript libraries set up like this:

```
   (function (global, undefined) {
      //..
    })(this)
```

What is the meaning of `undefined` in this context?

Comment: It's a frequently asked question here... let's look for another question to close it as duplicate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In older browsers, [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) wasn't *immutable* or *non-writable*. Setting `undefined` as a name for an unused *function* parameter meant that it was *undefined*, even if it got set in a higher scope.

```
// Old browser
undefined = 1;
undefined; // 1

// Modern browser
undefined = 1;
undefined; // undefined
```

It should be noted that the non-writability is only applicable in the global scope, in both cases the following is true;

```
(function () {         // creating a new scope means..
    var undefined = 1; // this is now different to the `undefined` global
    return undefined;  // so can be written to, e.g. set as 1
}()); // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `undefined` as a parameter of the function allow minifiers to replace it by a shorter name.

For example this:

```
(function (global, undefined) {
    alert(undefined)
})(this)
```

May be minified to this:

```
(function(a,b){alert(b)})(this)
```

So all occurrences of the `undefined` variable inside the function will be renamed to some short name like `b`. Irrespective of the variable name, it'll have the same value, and so will serve the same purpose.

Comment: what do you mean by shorter name? could you provide ma an example? thanks

Comment: A minifier might re-write the function to use `u` instead of `undefined`, saving some charaters.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your latest comment +1